# How can I drop just on specified drop div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/93n39bm8/

Hello. You have here my jsfiddle.
I've created a plugin and i'm stuck. 
I can't make the drag item to return to its original position if is not on it's drop element. If I drop it on another drop element it goes to its own drop element instead of going to its original position.
Please help me in this matter and point me to the right path.
js:

```
var height = $(window).height();
$("#draggable").height(height);
$("#droppable").height(height);
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dnd = function (opt) {

        opt = $.extend({
            drop: "",
            handle: "",
            cursor: "move"
        }, opt);

        if (opt.handle === "") {
            var $el = this;
            var $le = opt.drop;
        } else {
            var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
            var $le = this.find(opt.drop);
        }

        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function (e) {
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('drag');
            } else {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('drag');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function (e) {
                $('.drag').offset({
                    top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup", function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('drag').css('z-index', z_idx);
                });

            });
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup", function () {
            if (!$le) {
                $(this).css({
                    "left": "0",
                        "top": "0"
                });

            } else if ($le) {
                $(this).removeClass('drag').css({
                    "left": "0",
                        "top": "40px",
                        "margin": "auto",
                        "width": "100%",
                        "text-align": "center"
                }).removeAttr('id').appendTo($le);


            }
        });

    };

})(jQuery);
(function ($) {

    $.fn.rand = function (tree, childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (tree) $this = $(this).find(tree);
            var unsortedElems = $this.children(childElem);
            var elems = unsortedElems.clone();

            elems.sort(function () {
                return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            unsortedElems.eq(i).replaceWith(elems[i]);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
$("#draggable").rand();
$("#id1").dnd({
    drop: "#drop1"
});
$("#id2").dnd({
    drop: "#drop2"
});
```